# C# unexpected token ref in method invoke

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to get values of controls from another thread using the invoke method

In my thread I have

```
        double plane_a = 0, plane_b = 0, plane_c = 0;
        Invoke((Action<ref double, ref double, ref double>)GetOffsetPlane, ref plane_a, ref plane_b, ref plane_c);
```

And the main thread function is

```
    private void GetOffsetPlane(ref double plane_A, ref double plane_B, 
        ref double plane_C)
    {
        plane_A = (double)planeAupd.Value;
        plane_B = (double)planeBupd.Value;
        plane_C = (double)planeCupd.Value;
    }
```

I get the errors:

```
error CS1073: Unexpected token 'ref'
error CS1073: Unexpected token 'ref'
error CS1073: Unexpected token 'ref'
```

How do I change the Invoke method to use ref parameters correctly

Comment: `Action<T, T1, T2>` is a generic delegate, it does not support `ref` parameters.